# Where can i get the minimum system requirements?

Tags: hardware

I have tried u20 and u22 via a cd and a thumb drive on a Dell E351 AMD dual core machine with 8gb ram. I either get a grub and nothing else or just a flashing cursor. Nothing Loading. The ubuntu site has NO info on what hardware it needs minimum. ubuntu 9.04 loaded on the PC fine and boots from hard drive but i have yet to get 20 or 22 to load.